# Is is possible to automatically generate all user that is related to the other user in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, saas

I'm learning Odoo SaaS right now and I'm trying to create a relational database, you can imagine it as a organizational tree table, I don't know what's the best word for it, but its like that.

So for Example, I created a **HEAD PERSONNEL** and Brandon Freeman was working under him, and I can also see people working under Brandon too.

[image]

And then If I view Brandon Freeman's profile, I can see that on the head tab, **HEAD Personnel** will be there automatically and under him will be his two personnel

[image]

Is this possible to do in Odoo SaaS? I'm having a difficult time experimenting on this one since I can't post on their community, and the functions are already built in.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a matter of perspective. Seems to me that you are using Partners to try to build you organization chart and I think you better go using Employees that will also create Partners for you.

Something like this:

https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/manage-departments-managers-and-employees-with-odoo